# Count columns of select PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, linux, postgresql

I am doing a select on a table I know how many results I have using

> PQntuples()

function . But how can I get the number of columns? Is there any function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `PQnfields(const PGresult*)` - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html